# wx.lib.agw.ultimatelistctrl. Prohibit increasing the height of the element

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, wxpython

There is an object UltimateListCtrl

```
from wx.lib.agw import ultimatelistctrl as ULC

self._ulc_graphs = ULC.UltimateListCtrl(self, size = (-1, 150),
    agwStyle=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.LC_VRULES|wx.LC_HRULES|ULC.ULC_HAS_VARIABLE_ROW_HEIGHT|ULC.ULC_SINGLE_SEL)
```

This list contains six columns. Last column "Comment". Since This object does not allow direct editing of the element value in the nth column (only the 0th column can be edited). It was decided to insert a button into each row of the last column, clicking on which flies a dialog with wx.TextCtrl. The user enters a comment there, clicks OK and the text of the comment is entered in the last column of the nth item in the list. 5th column (if with 0):

```
self._ulc_graphs.InsertColumn(5, 'Комментарий', ULC.ULC_FORMAT_CENTER, 100)

# in the loop I add rows to the list
self._ulc_graphs.SetStringItem (self._ulc_graphs_index, 5, '')
button_comment = wx.Button(self._ulc_graphs, -1, '...', size=(23, 23))
self._ulc_graphs.SetItemWindow(self._ulc_graphs_index, 5, button_comment, False)
button_comment.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButtonComment)
self._ulcItem_btn[self._ulc_graphs_index] = button_comment
```

Result:

[image]

Of course, forcing a user to write text into one row is a bad idea. Therefore, i included the wx.TE_MULTILINE style for the wx.TextCtrl object. But when I insert multi-line text into the list cell, this cell increases its size: element height = number of lines in the text.

It looks awful, of course:

[image]

Can I ban it somehow (height increase)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misunderstood your problem but why don't you simply replace all line feeds in the dialog result.
Something along these lines:

```
def OnButtonComment(self,event):
    dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(self, "Comment", caption="Input Data",
            value="", style=wx.OK|wx.CANCEL|wx.TE_MULTILINE)
    dlg.ShowModal()
    txt = dlg.GetValue()
    txt = txt.replace('\n',' ')
    self.list.SetStringItem(self.index, 1, txt)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's exactly what I did. Only replaced by "0x00 ".